# What can explain the difference between php's process time and jQuery ajax result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering what could explain the difference between the time took by a php function called through AJAX and the time took by the jQuery.ajax() function to "success" it.

In other words, let's say I'm calling a `to_do()`php function through `jQuery.ajax()` :

The php function takes 0.009sec to process (I use microtime() to control it), while the jQuery.ajax() function takes 0.385sec to went from the `beforeSend` function to the `success` function (the `beforeSend` is just used to start the `console.time` that ends in the `success` one).

This "huge" difference does not make sense for me.

Comment: Once PHP is done processing, it has to be transported over HTTP which, depending on versions and protocols, involves various things such as handshakes, lookups and network latency.

Comment: Take your pick from: authentication middleware, firewalls, server load, (lack of) JS performance in general, cheap virtual hosting... etc.

Comment: It seems to be a huge difference for the "HTTP transport" but it makes more sense, thank you !